# Number of prime divisors in an interval

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility

I've found a problem on a c++ website and I don't know how to solve it. Given an interval [x,y] and a number K I have to find how many numbers from this interval have exactly K distinct prime divisors. For example [2,6] and K = 1 the numbers are: 2,3,4,5 so the answer is 4. Please help me solve this problem!

Comment: Yes you're right I corrected it!

Comment: Does the prime divisors mus be distinct? For example $8$ has 3 prime divisors, but only one distinct, because $8 = 2^3$

Comment: I corrected it ....they have to be distinct...also 8 has only one prime divisor: 2

Comment: @Stefan4024 $8$ has three prime _factors_ ($8 = 2\cdot 2\cdot 2$), but only one prime _divisor_ (the divisors of $8$ are $1,2,4,8$).

Comment: Could you post a link to the question, here in the comments?

Comment: I can't post the link as the language is not English

Comment: @user2128547: many users of mse do not have English as their mother tongue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Sieve of Eratosthenes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) to generate prime numbers $p \leq y$. Every time you find a new prime, update the number of prime divisors of each element of $[x,y]$ if needed.

Actually, you can stop the Sieve as soon as $p > \frac{y}{2\times 3 \times 5 \times \dots p_{K-1}}$ where $p_i$ is the $i$-th prime.